# How to insert a new row of values into a table and continue with my CTE (snowflake)

Tags: insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have CTE that looks like:

```
WITH COLS AS (
  SELECT VALUE AS COL FROM ET1 LIMIT 1
),
RAW_COLS_ORDER AS (
  SELECT TRY_CAST(SUBSTR(KEY, 2) AS NUMBER) AS COL_POS, VALUE --remove the c from the column aftersplitting the json
  FROM (
      SELECT KEY, VALUE::TEXT AS value
           FROM COLS, TABLE(FLATTEN (INPUT => COLS.COL))
    ) 
  ORDER BY COL_POS ASC
),

RAW_POS AS (
  SELECT (COL_POS + 3) AS COL_POSITION, VALUE 
  FROM RAW_COLS_ORDER
)
SELECT * FROM RAW_POS;
```

I want to insert a new row into my temporary table `RAW_COLS_ORDER`which has two columns "COL_POS" and "VALUE" with the value FOR COL_POS being 125 and the value for VALUE being "name". I am not sure how to add a new row to the RAW_COLS_ORDER table and continue on with creating the RAW_POS table using the previous tables. Is there a way I can do this without breaking the CTE? Would I have to use a `UNION`? (Also I have more temp tables building on the RAW_POS table)

Comment: Can you provide table info for ET1?

Comment: You should be able to use a UNION statement in the query used to produce RAW_COLS_ORDER.  That said, I don't think the ORDER BY clause in that query is doing anything for you ... the ORDER BY should be applied at the query that produces results for you, not the internal CTE.